# How to insert a Date type variable in MySQL through JSON

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, api

I've a table in the database that contains a field which is type Date. If I try to insert a date from postman through the API like this:

```
 {
   "registerDate" : "2014-06-02"
 }
```

It works, but then I try to do it from javascript with jquery taking the value from an input in the format YYYY-MM-DD or even giving to the variable the value "2014-06-02" it inserts a NULL value in the database.

```
 var user = new Object();
 user.registerDate = $('#register_date').val();
 createUser(url, type, JSON.stringify(user), function(user){
 });
```

or

```
 var user = new Object();
 user.registerDate = "2014-06-02";
 createUser(url, type, JSON.stringify(user), function(user){
 });
```

Where createUser is:

```
function createUser(url, type, user, success){
 $.ajax({
     url:url,
     type: 'POST',
     crossDomain : true,
     contentType : type,
     data : user
})
.done(function (data, status, jqxhr) {
      success(user);
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log(textStatus);
});
}
```

Where is the problem if in postman works but from JavaScript it doesn't?

Comment: What happens if you use `alert(user.registerDate)` right after you've retrieved its value?

Answer (score 1):

**As a suggestion** (a comment would be too big), you may want to convert your date to miliseconds using the [parse method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

```
Date.parse('2014-06-02');
```

Send that as a JSON:

```
{'registerDate' : '1401685200'}
```

And parse it back in MySQL using the [`FROM_UNIXTIME` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(1401685200)
```

Or even better, you can store your date as an `integer` value on your database and just convert it to a date whenever you need it; *since storing it as a string may cause issues with encoding*.